# How to make ST computation produce lazy result stream (or operate like a co-routine)?

Tags: python, haskell, generator, mutable, coroutine

I'm struggling with the general problem on how to make a stateful computation in Haskell generate results lazily. E.g. the following simple algorithm can be expressed with the help of Python's generator facility as a stateful but "lazy" computation, performing only the steps necessary to reach the next `yield` statement and then returning the control-flow to the caller until the next element is requested:

```py
def solveLP(vmax0, elems):
    elem_true_ixs = [ [ ei for ei, b in enumerate(row) if b ] for row in elems ]

    return go(vmax0, elem_true_ixs)

def go(vmax, mms):
    if not mms:
        yield []

    else:
        for ei in mms[0]:
            maxcnt = vmax[ei]

            if not maxcnt > 0:
                continue

            vmax[ei] = maxcnt-1 # modify vmax vector in-place
            for es in go(vmax, mms[1:]):
                # note: inefficient vector-concat operation
                # but not relevant for this question
                yield [ei]+es
            vmax[ei] = maxcnt   # restore original vmax state


for sol in solveLP([1,2,3],[[True,True,False],[True,False,True]]):
    print sol

# prints [0,2], [1,0], and [1,2]
```

This can be easily translated to a lazy Haskell computation (e.g. when `m` is specialized to `Logic` or `[]`), e.g.

```hs
import           Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU

solveLP :: MonadPlus m => VU.Vector Int -> [[Bool]] -> m [Int]
solveLP vmax0 elems = go vmax0 elemTrueIxs
  where
    -- could be fed to 'sequence'
    elemTrueIxs = [ [ ei | (ei,True) <- zip [0::Int ..] row ] | row <- elems ]

    go vmax []     = return []
    go vmax (m:ms) = do
        ei <- mlist m

        let vmax'  = vmax VU.// [(ei, maxcnt-1)] -- this operation is expensive
            maxcnt = vmax VU.! ei

        guard $ maxcnt > 0

        es <- go vmax' ms

        return $ (ei:es)

    mlist = msum . map return
```

...but I'd like to be able to get closer to the original Python implementation, by using mutable vectors, and modifying a single `vmax0` vector in-place (as I just need to increment/decrement a single element, and copying the whole vector just to replace a single element is quite an overhead the longer the vector becomes); please note that this is just a toy example for a class of algorithms I've been trying to implement

So my question is -- assuming there is a way to accomplish that -- how can I express such a stateful algorithm in the ST monad while still being able to return the results back to the caller as soon as they are produced during the computation? I've tried combining the ST monad with a list monad via monad-transformers but I couldn't figure out how to make it work...

Answer (score 3):

Just use lazy ST. In Haskell, plain old lists are basically identical to Python generators, so we'll return a list of results (where a result is an `[Int]`). Here's a transliteration of your Python code:

```
import Control.Monad.ST.Lazy
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

solveLP :: [Int] -> [[Bool]] -> [[Int]]
solveLP vmax_ elems_ = runST $ do
    vmax <- newListArray (0, length vmax_) vmax_
    let elems = map (findIndices id) elems_
    go vmax elems

go :: STArray s Int Int -> [[Int]] -> ST s [[Int]]
go vmax [] = return [[]]
go vmax (mm:mms) = liftM concat . forM mm $ \ei -> do
    maxcnt <- readArray vmax ei
    if not (maxcnt > 0) then return [] else do
        writeArray vmax ei (maxcnt - 1)
        rest <- go vmax mms
        writeArray vmax ei maxcnt
        return (map (ei:) rest)
```

Try e.g. `solveLP [1,undefined,3] [[True,True,False],[True,False,True]]` to see that it really does return results lazily.

Comment: Interesting (but why can't I use a `STUArray`?) but isn't this more like if the Python code would `yield` after restoring the `maxcnt` vector, i.e.: `vmax[ei] = maxcnt-1; ess = list(go(vmax, mms[1:])); vmax[ei] = maxcnt; for es in ess: return [ei]+es`?

Comment: For the first question: unboxing eliminates laziness. For the second question: the array is a piece of internal state, not observable to the outside world, so whether the yield happens before or after writing to the array is not observable.

Comment: @hvr ...actually, it is probably okay to use an unboxed array here. I agree that it's a bit annoying that there's no instance for unboxed arrays in the lazy ST monad, but you can wrap all the array operations with `strictToLazyST`. Is there a test instance that takes long enough to compute that we can observe whether this solution is still lazy? (We can't pull the trick in my answer of using `undefined`, because the array construction happens all at once.)

Comment: @hvr I wrote `let x = solveLP (replicate 100 1) (replicate 100 (replicate 100 True))` and executed in sequence: `x !! 1000`, `x !! 1000`, `x !! 2000`. These took 10, 0, and 10 seconds respectively, indicating to me that this solution (using `STUArray` and `lazyToStrictST` everywhere) is sufficiently lazy. I think I'll file a feature request for an appropriate `MArray` instance.

Comment: what I don't get though is, why is your `ST`-based `solveLP` implementation that much slower than the non-`ST` version provided in my question? even requesting only the first solution for that 100^2 problem instance with `head` takes several seconds, whereas the non-`ST` implementation responds in less than a millisecond?

Comment: @hvr Could not reproduce: ghci reports that it takes 0.02 seconds to evaluate `head x` for both your code and my `ST`-based code.

Answer (score 2):

It's too early in the morning for me to put in time understanding your algorithm. But if I read the underlying question right, you can use lazy ST.  Here's a trivial example:

```
import Control.Monad.ST.Lazy
import Data.STRef.Lazy

generator :: ST s [Integer]
generator = do
    r <- newSTRef 0
    let loop = do
            x <- readSTRef r
            writeSTRef r $ x + 1
            xs <- loop
            return $ x : xs
    loop

main :: IO ()
main = print . take 25 $ runST generator
```

It is exactly creating a lazy result stream from an ST action that maintains its state.

Comment: The shared state in this case cannot be stored in a `STRef`, so the answer isn't as simple as this.

Comment: @dflemstr The shared state *can*, however, be stored in an `STArray`, so the answer really is as simple as this.

Comment: @DanielWagner, yes, using `STArray`s, it is possible; however, I don't see this answer dealing with the quirks of using `STArray`s :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's make a more direct translation of the Python code. You are using coroutines in Python, so why not just use coroutines in Haskell? Then there is the issue of mutable vectors; see more details below.

First of all, tons of imports:

```
-- Import some coroutines
import Control.Monad.Coroutine -- from package monad-coroutine

-- We want to support "yield" functionality like in Python, so import it:
import Control.Monad.Coroutine.SuspensionFunctors (Yield(..), yield)

-- Use the lazy version of ST for statefulness
import Control.Monad.ST.Lazy

-- Monad utilities
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)

-- Immutable and mutable vectors
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector
import Data.Vector.Mutable (STVector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as Vector
```

Here are some utility definitions that let us treat coroutines as if they behaved like in Python, more or less:

```
-- A generator that behaves like a "generator function" in Python
type Generator m a = Coroutine (Yield a) m ()

-- Run a generator, collecting the results into a list
generateList :: Monad m => Generator m a -> m [a]
generateList generator = do
  s <- resume generator -- Continue where we left off
  case s of
    -- The function exited and returned a value; we don't care about the value
    Right _ -> return []
    -- The function has `yield`ed a value, namely `x`
    Left (Yield x cont) -> do
      -- Run the rest of the function
      xs <- generateList cont
      return (x : xs)
```

Now we need to be able to use `STVector`s somehow. You stated that you wanted to use **lazy** ST, and the pre-defined operations on `STVector`s are only defined for **strict** ST, so we need to make a few wrapper functions. I'm not into making operators for stuff like this, but you could if you really want to make the code pythonic (E.g. `$=` for `writeLazy` or whatever; you need to handle the index projection somehow, but it might be possible to make it look nicer anyways).

```
writeLazy :: STVector s a -> Int -> a -> ST s ()
writeLazy vec idx val = strictToLazyST $ Vector.write vec idx val

readLazy :: STVector s a -> Int -> ST s a
readLazy vec idx = strictToLazyST $ Vector.read vec idx

thawLazy :: Vector a -> ST s (STVector s a)
thawLazy = strictToLazyST . Vector.thaw
```

All the tools are here, so let's just translate the algorithm:

```
solveLP :: STVector s Int -> [[Bool]] -> Generator (ST s) [Int]
solveLP vmax0 elems =
  go vmax0 elemTrueIxs
  where
    elemTrueIxs = [[ei | (ei, True) <- zip [0 :: Int ..] row] | row <- elems]

go :: STVector s Int -> [[Int]] -> Generator (ST s) [Int]
go _ [] = yield []
go vmax (m : ms) = do
  forM_ m $ \ ei -> do
    maxcnt <- lift $ readLazy vmax ei
    when (maxcnt > 0) $ do
      lift $ writeLazy vmax ei $ maxcnt - 1
      sublist <- lift . generateList $ go vmax ms
      forM_ sublist $ \ es -> yield $ ei : es
      lift $ writeLazy vmax ei maxcnt
```

Sadly, nobody has bothered to define `MonadPlus` for `Coroutine`s, so `guard` isn't available here. But that's probably not what you wanted anyways, since it raises an error when halting in some/most monads. We also of course need to `lift` all operations done in the `ST` monad out of the `Coroutine` monad; a minor nuisance.

That's all the code, so one can simply run it:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  forM_ list print
  where
    list =  runST $ do
      vmax <- thawLazy . Vector.fromList $ [1, 2, 3]
      generateList (solveLP vmax [[True, True, False], [True, False, True]])
```

The `list` variable is pure and lazily generated.

I'm kind of tired, so if something doesn't make sense, please don't hesitate to point it out.

Comment: This very informative, but did you mix up `STArray` with `STVector` in your answer?

Comment: No, I did not. `STVector`s are defined in `Data.Vector.Mutable` as seen in the imports.

Comment: I was referring to the part where you state "Now we need to be able to use STArrays somehow." and then go on to use `STVector` instead